# Qual a diferença de um WCF Service para um Duplex Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, signalr

Segue as dúvidas...

1- Qual a diferença de um WCF Service para um Duplex Service?

2- Quando usar um Duplex Service?

3- Podemos comparar ele ao SignalR?

Answer (score 2):

> Qual a diferença de um WCF Service para um Duplex Service?

No WCF podemos configurar os tipos de mensagens trocadas entre cliente e o serviço WCF, **Duplex** é um desses tipos de mensagens:

Em um serviço WCF configurado para troca de mensagens do tipo **Duplex** o cliente realiza a chamada a uma operação disponibilizada e continua trabalhando, mas em algum momento o serviço WCF envia uma resposta ao cliente (callback), para que com base nesse retorno o cliente possa tomar uma decisão.

> Quando usar um Duplex Service?

Em um cenário que você precisa do retorno do seu serviço WCF para tomar uma decisão.

Suponha que um determinado serviço WCF, você esteja chamando um método para *MeuServicoWCF.FecharVenda(...)*. Porém, você sinta necessidade de que seu serviço WCF deva notificar o cliente de que algum evento ocorreu (fazendo uma chamada a um método do cliente), imaginemos que "o estoque acabou e algum outro método precisa ser invocado no cliente para tratar isso". Assim você da ao cliente, uma chance de conseguir uma melhor interação com o serviço WCF.

Isso permite uma **comunicação bidirecional**, ou seja, o cliente invocar método de um serviço, bem como um serviço invocar um método do cliente.

> Podemos comparar ele ao SignalR?

No que diz respeito a implementação, eu nunca implementei uma aplicação em SignalR, então não sei comparar a nível de implementação, mas grosso modo:

Asp.net **SignalR** é uma biblioteca open-source que facilita a implementação de comunicação em **tempo real** (exemplo Chats, Cotação de ações em tempo real, Jogos), atualizações/notificações de forma assíncrona em uma aplicação.

**WCF** é uma parte da .NET Framework que fornece um modelo unificado de programação para construir de forma rápida aplicações distribuidas orientadas a serviço (SOA). O WCF representa uma camada de comunicação independente e simplifica a implementação e configuração de um **aplicativo distribuído**.